# mysql syntax error in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm getting an error Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5,7,6,9,13 ORDER BY n.date DESC' at line 5. Can anyone point out what's wrong? Thanks

```
$news_query = 'SELECT u.id as userId, u.username, n.id as newsId, n.action, n.date 
            FROM newsfeed as n 
            JOIN users as u on n.userId = u.id
            WHERE
            userId in '.implode(',', array_map('intval', $myfriends)).' &&   
            userId == :myId             // posts by me
            ORDER BY n.date DESC
        ';
```

Answer (score 5):

The comparison operator:

```
 userId == :myId
```

In SQL the equality operator is `=`, not `==`.

From the error message it appears that the above snippet, when the value is inserted into the query, looks like this:

```
userId == 5,7,6,9,13
```

That is not a valid comparison, even if you used the right operator. If you want to compare `userId` against a list of values then you should use the `IN` operator and a tuple (a set of values):

```
userId IN (5,7,6,9,13)
```

**Response to comment**

You could change your code to:

```
$tuple = implode(',', array_map('intval', $myfriends));
$news_query = <<< SQL
    SELECT
        u.id AS userId,
        u.username,
        n.id AS newsId,
        n.action,
        n.date 
    FROM
        newsfeed AS n 
    JOIN
        users AS u ON n.userId = u.id
    WHERE
        userId IN ($tuple) AND
        userId = :myId
    ORDER BY
        n.date DESC
SQL;
```

You should also qualify the `userId` field in the `WHERE` clause; i.e. put `u.` or `n.` in-front of it, so that there is no ambiguity.

Comment: So would it be more so like this? `$news_query = 'SELECT u.id as userId, u.username, n.id as newsId, n.action, n.date 
    FROM newsfeed as n 
    JOIN users as u on n.userId = u.id
    WHERE
    userId in ('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $myfriends)).') &&   
    userId = :myId             // posts by me
    ORDER BY n.date DESC
   ';`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your list in parentheses here:

```
WHERE userId in ('.implode(',', array_map('intval', $myfriends)).') &&
                ^ here                                            ^ and here
```

and on the next line replace `==` with `=` (thanks to jeroen for picking this up)

```
userId = :myId 
       ^ here
```

Comment: I'm getting this now Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':myId // posts by me ORDER BY n.date DESC' at line 5. Any idea why? Thanks though